# Kafka Producer causes org.apache.kafka.common.network.InvalidReceiveException: Invalid receive

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, terraform, kafka-producer-api, kafka-topic

I am running 3-zookeeper-cluster and 3-kafka-cluster on Kubernetes.
Kafka seems to be running.
However if I produce some message to a topic and check the topic, there's no message at all.

Here's my broker saying. That says some invalid receive or something, the funny thing is trying to make topics work well but producing.
also I could watch topics or schemas which i made early on Topics-ui which is GUI tool for broker.
Schema-registry, Connect, Rest's log is fine so the broker seems to be running well.

```
org.apache.kafka.common.network.InvalidReceiveException: Invalid receive (size = 1195725856 larger than 104857600)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:424)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:385)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:651)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:572)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:483)
    at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:863)
    at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:762)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:424)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:385)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:651)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:572)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:483)
    at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:863)
    at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:762)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

and here's my broker configurations with **terraform**
**Statefulset**

```
          port {
            container_port = 9092
          }   

          env {
            name = "KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR" 
            value = "3" 
          }   

          env {
            name = "KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR" 
            value = "3" 
          }   

          env {
            name = "KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP" 
            value = "PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT"
          }   

          env {
            name = "KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT"
            value = "lucent-zookeeper-0.zookeeper-service.default:2181,lucent-zookeeper-1.zookeeper-service.default:2181,lucent-zookeeper-2.zookeeper-service.default:2181"
          }   

          env {
            name = "POD_IP"

            value_from {
              field_ref {
                field_path = "status.podIP"
              }   
            }   
          }   

          env {
            name = "HOST_IP"
            value_from {
              field_ref {
                field_path = "status.hostIP"
              }   
            }   
          }   

          env {
            name = "POD_NAME"

            value_from {
              field_ref {
                field_path = "metadata.name"
              }   
            }   
          }   

          env {
            name = "POD_NAMESPACE"

            value_from {
              field_ref {
                field_path = "metadata.namespace"
              }   
            }   
          }   

          command = [ 
            "sh",
            "-exec",
            "export KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://$${POD_NAME}.kafka-service.$${POD_NAMESPACE}:9092 && export KAFKA_BROKER_ID=$${HOSTNAME##*-} && exec /etc/confluent/docker/run"
          ]
```

**service**

```
resource "kubernetes_service" "kafka-service" {
  metadata {
    name = "kafka-service"

    labels = {
      app = "broker" 
    }
  }

  spec {
    selector = {
      app = "broker"
    }

    port {
      port = 9092
    }

    cluster_ip = "None"
  }
```

**code to try produce**

```
kafka-console-producer --broker-list kafka-service:9092 --topic test
```

Comment: Looks like your message size is bigger than the default 1 MB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My initial guess would be that you might be trying to receive a request that is too large. The maximum size is the default size for `socket.request.max.bytes`, which is 100MB. So if you have a message which is bigger than 100MB try to increase the value of this variable under `server.properties`.

Comment: Umm great it literally can solve the problem. Also it's great idea for ignoring the invalid message logs.
As I check more, that invalid data was from EKS and it seems to be http request to Kafka. 
So I found and removed the thing and it's done. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It can also happen if you tried to connect to a non-SSL listener, as if it was SSL.
Verify that 9092 is the SSL listener port on the broker. Source: https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/issues/1680#issuecomment-364883669